# SQL script to partition data on a column and return the max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a requirement to compute bonus payout based on **spread goal** and **date achieved** as follows:

```
Spread Goal | Date Achieved     | Bonus Payout
---------------------------------------------- 
$3,500      | < 27 wks          | $2,000 
$3,500      | 27 wks to 34 wks  | $1,000 
$3,500      | > 34 wks          | $0
```

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 where the subset of the data is as follows:

```
EMP_ID   WK_NUM   NET_SPRD_LCL 
123      10       0 
123      11       1500 
123      15       3600 
123      18       3800 
123      19       4000
```

Based on the requirement, I need to look for records where `NET_SPRD_LCL` is greater than or equal to `3500` during 2 *continuous* `wk_num`.

So, in my example, `WK_NUM` 15 and 18 (which in my case are *continuous* because  I have a calendar table that I join to to exclude the *holiday weeks*) are less than `27 wks` and have `NET_SPRD_LCL > 3500`.

For this case, I want to output the `MAX(WK_NUM)`, it's associated `NET_SPRD_LCL` and `BONUSPAYOUT = 2000`. So, the output should be as follows:

```
EMP_ID   WK_NUM   NET_SPRD_LCL   BONUSPAYOUT
123      18       3800           2000
```

If this meets the first requirement, the script should output and quit. If not, then I will look for the second requirement where `Date Achieved` is between `27 wks to 34 wks`.

I hope I was able to explain my requirement clearly :-)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how can weeks 15 and 18 be continuous? is there no data for weeks 16 and 17?

Comment: I guess weeks 18 and 19 are the case you need.

Comment: @btberry My aplogies. I wasn't getting enough traction in the other question. That's why I posted a new one with better explanation. In terms of best practices, is it better to just amend my initial question with the updated explanation>

Comment: @vkp there are cases where weeks aren't always continuous. The requirement is to skip weeks that have a holidy. So, the data for the week of July 4th will have to be excluded.

Comment: If you need to exclude some weeks due holidays - you need some calendar table. In your sample you take 15 and 18, so 2 weeks are cut off, why?

Comment: @gofr1 I have a calendar table that I join to to exclude the "holiday weeks". I was in a rush to create a sample, so I should probably have used week_num 15 and 17 to indicate that week_num 16 was a holiday week. I hope this helps.

Comment: That is good! So we can say that all week nums are continuous and can check every one of them? what if you got week 1, 3600, week 2, 3700, week 3, 4000 - how to count this once? We will take 1 and 2, and 3rd will not be counted? Or we should take 1, 2 and 2, 3 to count bonus?

Comment: @gofr1, yes, we can check every one of them. As for the situation you described, we will take 1 and 2 to count bonus. We are essentially looking for the 2nd continuous WK_NUM when they reached the "spread goal", i.e. >= 3500. So, we can ignore the 3rd week.

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question! I broke my mind on situations like 4 rows in a turn are with 3500 and more. And came up with this.

You can use CTE, recursive CTE and ROW_NUMBER():

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT  EMP_ID, 
        WK_NUM, 
        NET_SPRD_LCL,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY WK_NUM) rn
FROM YourTable
)
, recur AS (
SELECT  EMP_ID,
        WK_NUM, 
        NET_SPRD_LCL,
        rn,
        1 as lev
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  c.EMP_ID,
        c.WK_NUM, 
        c.NET_SPRD_LCL,
        c.rn,
        CASE WHEN c.NET_SPRD_LCL < 3500 THEN Lev+1 ELSE Lev END 
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN recur r
    ON r.rn+1 = c.rn
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
                    EMP_ID,
                    WK_NUM, 
                    NET_SPRD_LCL,
                    CASE WHEN WK_NUM < 27 THEN $2000
                            WHEN WK_NUM between 27 and 34 THEN $1000
                            ELSE $0 END as Bonus
FROM recur
WHERE NET_SPRD_LCL >= 3500
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMP_ID,lev ORDER BY WK_NUM)%2
```

Output for data you provided:

```
EMP_ID  WK_NUM  NET_SPRD_LCL    Bonus
123     18      3800            2000,00
```

Comment: I will definitely give it a try. I was able to use the LAG window function to come up with a solution. But it turned out to be a bit inelegant. By the way, how can I paste my solution here? The number of characters allowed when commenting isn't enough to post my entire script.

Comment: You can add this to your question!